# Get value from ace editor in webview to react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, ace-editor

I want to get the value written in the editor that I implemented via webview into react native. I followed the great example given here [Get value from input field in webview to react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71590085/get-value-from-input-field-in-webview-to-react-native) but it won't work with my current setup. This my webview:

```
  let html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.14/ace.js"></script>        
</head>

<body onload="ready()">
    <div id='container'>
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab_editor')" id="defaultOpen">Editor</button>
            <button id="output" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab_output');">Output</button>
        </div>

        <div id="tab_editor" class="tabcontent">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab_output" class="tabcontent">
            <iframe id='iframe' frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

            if (tabName == "tab_output") {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    update();
                }, 100);
            }

        }

       document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>

    <script>
        function update() {
            var idoc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
            idoc.open();
            idoc.write(editor.getValue());
            idoc.close();
        }

  
function getValue() {
       let answer = editor.getValue();
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(answer);              
     };

        function setupEditor() {

            window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
            editor.focus();


            editor.setOptions({
                fontSize: "12pt",
                wrap: 1,
                         });
                    }

        function ready() {
            setupEditor();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So I try to get the value from the editor via

```
function getValue() {
       let answer = editor.getValue();
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(answer);              
     };
```

In my react native component I then added:

```
const myAmazingComponent= (props) => {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("I want to change after user Input");

...

return (
   <WebView
          ref={(r) => (webref = r)}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true} // To prevent crash when opening screen
          scalesPageToFit={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          source={{ html }}
          injectedJavaScript={props.defaultContent} // What is shown when screen loads
          // onMessage={(event) => {
          //   alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
          // }}
          onMessage={(event) => {
            console.log("EVENT-DATA:", event);
            setAnswer(event.nativeEvent.data);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text>{answer}</Text>
)
```

However nothing I type in the editor is saved in "answer".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useContext, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const AnswerContainer_press = (props) => {
  let html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.14/ace.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        #editor {
            height: 100%;
            /* width: 50%; */
            /* display: inline-block; */
        }
        
        #container {
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #iframe {
            height: 100%;
            /* display: inline-block; */
            /* width: 50%; */
        }
        /* disable tag matching */
        
        .ace_editor .ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket {
            display: none
        }
        /* Style the tab */
        
        .tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            background-color: #ECEAFF;
        }
        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
        
        .tab button {
            background-color: #ECEAFF;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #5B5779
        }

        // #output {
        // color: #000000
        // }

 
        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
        
        .tab button:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        /* Create an active/current tablink class */
        
        .tab button.active {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        /* Style the tab content */
        
        .tabcontent {
            display: none;
            /* padding: 6px 12px; */
            border: 1px solid #333;
            border-top: none;
       
        }
        
        #tab_editor,
        #tab_output {
            height: 100%;
           }
    </style>

</head>

<body onload="ready()">
    <div id='container'>
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab_editor')" id="defaultOpen">Editor</button>
            <button id="output" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab_output');">Output</button>
        </div>

        <div id="tab_editor" class="tabcontent">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab_output" class="tabcontent">
            <iframe id='iframe' frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

            if (tabName == "tab_output") {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    update();
                }, 100);
            }

        }

        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>

    <script>
        function update() {
            var idoc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
            idoc.open();
            idoc.write(editor.getValue());
            idoc.close();
        }

let userAnswer = "";
  
function getValue() {
       var editor = ace.edit("editor");
       var answer = editor.getValue();
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(answer);              
     };
   var editor = ace.edit("editor");
   
   editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
       
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(editor.getSession().getValue())
   });

        function setupEditor() {

            window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
            // editor.setValue("Type your code here...", 1); //1 = moves cursor to end
            // editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
            //     update();
            // });

            editor.focus();


            editor.setOptions({
                fontSize: "12pt",
                showLineNumbers: false,
                showGutter: false,
                vScrollBarAlwaysVisible: false,
                enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
                enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
                wrap: 34,
                indentedSoftWrap: false,
                        });

            editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
            editor.setBehavioursEnabled(false);
        }

        function ready() {
            setupEditor();
        }
        // setupEditor();
        // update();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
`;

  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("I want to change after user Input");

  /* Button visibility 
 Make buttons disappear after being tapped*/

  const [button_1_Visibility, setButton_1_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_1_Visibility
  );
  const [button_2_Visibility, setButton_2_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_2_Visibility
  );
  const [button_3_Visibility, setButton_3_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_3_Visibility
  );
  const [button_4_Visibility, setButton_4_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_4_Visibility
  );
  const [button_5_Visibility, setButton_5_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_5_Visibility
  );
  const [button_6_Visibility, setButton_6_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_6_Visibility
  );
  const [button_7_Visibility, setButton_7_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_7_Visibility
  );
  const [button_8_Visibility, setButton_8_Visibility] = useState(
    props.answer_8_Visibility
  );

  const answer_1 = props.answer_1;
  const answer_2 = props.answer_2;
  const answer_3 = props.answer_3;
  const answer_4 = props.answer_4;
  const answer_5 = props.answer_5;
  const answer_6 = props.answer_6;
  const answer_7 = props.answer_7;
  const answer_8 = props.answer_8;

  const clearField = `
  userAnswer = ""
  editor.setValue(userAnswer, 1);
    `;

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "65%", marginTop: 70 }}>
        <WebView
          ref={(r) => (webref = r)}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
          scalesPageToFit={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          source={{ html }}
          injectedJavaScript={props.defaultContent}
          onMessage={(event) => {
            console.log("EVENT-DATA:", event);
            setAnswer(event.nativeEvent.data);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text>{answer}</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_1_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_1_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_1_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_1);
            setButton_1_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_1_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 2 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_2_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_2_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_2_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_2);
            setButton_2_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_2_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 3 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_3_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_3_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_3_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_3);
            setButton_3_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_3_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 4 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_4_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_4_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_4_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_4);
            setButton_4_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_4_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 5 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_5_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_5_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_5_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_5);
            setButton_5_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_5_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 6 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_6_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_6_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_6_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_6);
            setButton_6_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_6_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 7 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_7_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_7_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_7_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_7);
            setButton_7_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_7_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
        {/* BUTTON 8 */}
        <Pressable
          style={
            button_8_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt
              : button_8_Visibility === true
              ? styles.submitBt_Dark
              : styles.submitBt_hide
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.answer_8_Letter();
            webref.injectJavaScript(answer_8);
            setButton_8_Visibility(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text
              style={styles.submitButtonText || styles.submitButtonText_Dark}
            >
              {props.answer_8_Label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>

        <Pressable
          style={styles.redoBt || styles.redoBt_Dark}
          onPress={() => {
            webref.injectJavaScript(clearField);
            webref.injectJavaScript(props.defaultContent);
            //props.redoButton();
            setButton_1_Visibility(props.answer_1_Visibility);
            setButton_2_Visibility(props.answer_2_Visibility);
            setButton_3_Visibility(props.answer_3_Visibility);
            setButton_4_Visibility(props.answer_4_Visibility);
            setButton_5_Visibility(props.answer_5_Visibility);
            setButton_6_Visibility(props.answer_6_Visibility);
            setButton_7_Visibility(props.answer_7_Visibility);
            setButton_8_Visibility(props.answer_8_Visibility);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.submitBtTextContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.RedoButtonText}>
              <FontAwesome name="repeat" size={20} color="#ffffff" /> Redo
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonContainer: {
    position: "relative",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginTop: 80,
  },
  submitBt: {
    position: "relative",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#D9E3EC",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "#BAD8EF",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.45,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowColor: "#B2C9DF",
    elevation: 2,
  },

  submitBt_Dark: {
    position: "relative",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#555555",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#333333",
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.45,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    elevation: 2,
  },

  submitBt_hide: {
    display: "none",
  },

  redoBt: {
    position: "relative",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#B7C9D9",
  },

  redoBt_Dark: {
    position: "relative",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#292929",
  },

  submitBtTextContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 12,
  },
  submitButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#2A3244",
  },
  submitButtonText_Dark: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#F3F3F3",
  },
  RedoButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#ffffff",
  },
  RedoButtonText_Dark: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#F3F3F3",
  },
});

export default AnswerContainer_press;
```

output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLnci.jpg)

Comment: Hi - thank you very much. Could you specify your answer? Where should I replace div?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: expo snack link https://snack.expo.dev/@alihaxan/code-editor